# How to get resource from ninject without using constructor pattern in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, ninject

When using Ninject with mvc3 we do something like, install ninject,  registerger modules-or-services .

We write control like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHelloService _service;
    public HomeController(IHelloService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public string Index()
    {
        return _service.GetGreeting();
    }
}
```

### I want to do something like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHelloService _service;

    /*
          No default constructor
    */

    public string Index()
    {
        _service= Ask_Ninject_to_provide_resource
        return _service.GetGreeting();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you **not** want a default constructor?

Comment: tell me how to use default constructor when one of my routehandler needs to access service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHelloService _service;

    /*
          No default constructor
    */

    public string Index()
    {
        _service= DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IHelloService>();
        return _service.GetGreeting();
    }
}
```

Though I would seriously question the need to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Your current practice of writing controls is better than what you are proposing. You want to be able to inject through fields, rather than constructor. This is a bad idea and it's not recommended.

Quote from [Ninject wiki](http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Injection%20Patterns):

*"Although its simplicity is tempting, you should generally try to avoid using field injection, since the value can then only be set via Ninject. This makes unit testing much more complex, since sometimes it's easiest to use dependency injection by hand to inject mock objects into your unit tests. (Unit testing with Ninject is covered in more depth later.)"*

Alternative is to inject through properties, but once again, you have to have a very good reason to do so. Most of the time constructor injection should do the job.